# How to solve altair problems in python

Tags: python, graph, charts, altair

I want to make a chart with 2 values using altair, but the chart result did not meet my expectation. I want to make a chart with 2 different colors and a legend for describing each value. I tried this code, but the result always gives me one colors, and the legend returns undefined. Below is my code.

```
chart = alt.Chart(hlos_sort_csv).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X('d', title = 'Distance'),
    y=alt.Y('BER-NRZ', title='BER'),
    color=alt.Color('Origin:N', legend=alt.Legend(title='Modulation')),
    tooltip=['d', 'BER-NRZ']
).properties(
    width=400,
    height=300,
    title='BER vs Distance'
)

#color=alt.Color('Origin:N', legend=alt.Legend(title='Origin'))

chart += alt.Chart(hlos_sort_csv).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X('d', title = 'Distance'),
    y=alt.Y('BER-RZ', title='BER'),
    color=alt.Color(value='#FF0000', legend=alt.Legend(title='Modulation')),
    tooltip=['d', 'BER-RZ']
).properties(
    width=400,
    height=300,
    title='BER vs Distance'
)

chart.configure_axis(
    labelFontSize=12,
    titleFontSize=14
).configure_title(
    fontSize=16
).configure_legend(
    title=None,
    direction='vertical',
    labelFontSize=12,
    symbolSize=100
)

chart
```

I want chart to be like this with legend beside chart:
[image]

But always return this
[image]

Comment: The easiest solution would be to change your data into long-form and then use a column from the dataframe as an indicator of the groups to color by  (nrz and rz). For details, see the docs https://joelostblom.github.io/altair-docs/user_guide/data.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data